# MongoDB performance with $and operator

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm running differents queries:

Filtering by geoJsonExtent, it is a polygon with 5 points.

```
db.Zone.find({ 
    "geoJsonExtent": { "$geoIntersects": { "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -103.342280, 20.671379 ] } } }  
}).explain("executionStats");

"executionSuccess" : true,
"executionTimeMillis" : 0,
"nReturned" : 7,
"totalDocsExamined" : 10,
"totalKeysExamined" : 19
```

Filtering by geoJson, it is a multipolygon with n points (hundreds).

```
db.Zone.find({ 
    "geoJson": { "$geoIntersects": { "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -103.342280, 20.671379 ] } } }, 
}).explain("executionStats");

"executionSuccess" : true,
"executionTimeMillis" : 2,
"nReturned" : 4,
"totalDocsExamined" : 6,
"totalKeysExamined" : 16
```

Filtering with and operator with both queries.

```
db.Zone.find({ 
    "geoJsonExtent": { "$geoIntersects": { "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -103.342280, 20.671379 ] } } },
    "geoJson": { "$geoIntersects": { "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -103.342280, 20.671379 ] } } }, 
}).explain("executionStats");

"executionSuccess" : true,
"executionTimeMillis" : 22,
"nReturned" : 4,
"totalDocsExamined" : 6,
"totalKeysExamined" : 16
```

I have 2dsphere indexes for geoJson and geoJsonExtent.

The last query is the slowest (22ms), but $and operator uses short-circuit evaluation so the last one query must be faster than the second one, because de first one is almost immediate.

Someone has any idea why is happening this?

Comment: "short circuit evaluation" is a concept relative to **OR** conditions so actually that does not apply. Also take a good look at the explain stats. A `$geoIntersects` does not "require" a 2dsphere index, so it may not even be used if the optimizer  deems it so. And of course you cannot have 2 geospatial indexes in use on a collection, nor compound with another geospatial data field. So at the very least there is part of the execution that cannot possibly use the index. All a bit too broad, and would need you to post all of the stats for a full commentary anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn That's not true, both `and` and `or` can support (and usually do) short circuiting. `a and b` does not evaluate `b` if `a` is false.

Comment: really, @and uses  short-circuit evaluation, you can check it in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/. I'm using 2dsphere index to optimize queries, I know it isn't required with $geoIntersects. What stats do you need? I thinked would be enough with query, index and execution time. Thanks a lot for your answers.